# TypeError: ‚int‘ object is not subscriptable in blackjack game using random.choices

Tags: python, typeerror, blackjack

I get a `TypeError int object is not subscriptable` and my code is unfinished I just want to know where my mistake is and how can I fix it, Thanks :)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\TOSHIBA\.spyder-py3\untitled1.py", line 40, in <module>
    print('You have:' , card_values(player_hand)) # telling the player's value if he stands

  File "C:\Users\TOSHIBA\.spyder-py3\untitled1.py", line 19, in card_values
    if (i[0:1] == 'J' or i[0:1] == 'Q' or i[0:1] == 'K' or i[0:1] == 10):

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

This is the error I get

```
#Code Begins

print('Welcome to BLACKJACK!') # welcome message

import random #importing random function
cards = ['A', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'J', 'Q','K'] # list for the cards with mixed data types
player_hand = random.choices(cards, k=2) #Drawing the player's cards(hand)
dealer_hand = random.choices(cards, k=2) #Drawing the dealer's cards(hand)

def card_values(the_hand): #function to calculate card values
    the_count = 0 
    ace_count = 0
    for i in the_hand:
        if (i[0:1] == 'J' or i[0:1] == 'Q' or i[0:1] == 'K' or i[0:1] == 10):
            the_count +=10
        elif (i[0:1] != 'A'):
            the_count += int(cards[0:1])
        else:
            ace_count +=1
    if (ace_count == 1 and the_count <= 10):
         the_count += 11
    elif(ace_count != 0):
         the_count += 1
    return the_count 

print ('Your cards are:' , player_hand) #printing the hands
print ("The dealer's cards are:" , '[' ,'X', ',', dealer_hand[0],  ']') #printing the hands


game = input('What would you like to do? H = HIT ME or S = Stand:  ')   #asking the user to hit or stand

if game == 'Hit': #drawing a card to the player's hand if he hits
    player_hand = random.choices(cards , k=1)
else:
    print('You have:' , card_values(player_hand)) # telling the player's value if he stands

while card_values(dealer_hand) <= 16: #adding a card if the dealer's hand is less than 16
    dealer_hand = random.choices(cards , k=1)
```

Comment: `int(cards[0:1])` is `int(['A'])`. Did you mean `the_count += i` instead ?

Comment: Care to include which line is throwing the error so someone can actually help you? Dumping 50 lines of code in a thread and adding "find my problem" doesn't deserve an answer. Imagine if your editor did that "Error: some error somewhere figure it out". You are that editor (right now).

Comment: I just edited and added it in @MichaelGuidry :)

Comment: If one of these answers has solved your problem please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While @Michael Guidry's answer is correct, I would like to build on it to address the style issues.

You can put the `card_values` definition at the top before the cards and hands because those are not relevant yet. Using explicit variable names is much better for reading and comprehension so I replaced with `for i in the_hand:` with `for card in the_hand:`. The choices are now sorted in an order that's easier to understand (*if ace/elif figures/else others* rather than if *figures or 10/elif not ace/else others*). The hit/stand choice is now encased in a while loop to ask the question again in case the user does not reply "H" or "S" but something that is not supported.

```
import random # Importing random function.

def card_values(the_hand):
    """This function calculate the values of a given hand."""

    the_count = 0 
    ace_count = 0
    for card in the_hand:
        if card == "A":
            ace_count += 1
        elif card in ("J", "Q", "K"):
            the_count += 10
        else:
            the_count += card
    if ace_count == 1 and the_count <= 10:
        the_count += 11
    elif ace_count != 0:
        the_count += 1
    return the_count 

# This is where the game starts.
cards = ['A', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'J', 'Q','K'] # List for the cards with mixed data types.
player_hand = random.choices(cards, k=2) # Drawing the player's cards (hand).
dealer_hand = random.choices(cards, k=2) # Drawing the dealer's cards (hand).
print('Your cards are:', player_hand) # Printing the hands.
print("The dealer's cards are:", '[' ,'X', ',', dealer_hand[0],  ']') # Printing the hands.   

# Ask the user to hit or stand. Repeat until the input is valid.
while True:
    choice = input('What would you like to do? H = HIT ME or S = Stand:  ')
    if choice in ("H", "S"):
        break
    else:
        print(f'Your choice "{choice}" is not supported, please provide the input again.)'

if choice == "H": # Drawing a card to the player's hand if he hits.
    player_hand = random.choices(cards , k=1)
else:
    print(player_hand)
    print('You have: ', card_values(player_hand)) # Telling the player's value if he stands.

while card_values(dealer_hand) <= 16: # Adding a card if the dealer's hand is less than 16.
    dealer_hand = random.choices(cards , k=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is simple: `i` is not subscriptable because `i` is the value. After you fix that your next error will be this part `the_count += int(cards[0:1])` which should be `the_count += i`.

**full example**

```
import random #importing random function
cards = ['A', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'J', 'Q','K'] # list for the cards with mixed data types
player_hand = random.choices(cards, k=2) #Drawing the player's cards(hand)
dealer_hand = random.choices(cards, k=2) #Drawing the dealer's cards(hand)

def card_values(the_hand): #function to calculate card values
    the_count = 0 
    ace_count = 0
    for i in the_hand:
        if i in ('J', 'Q', 'K', 10):
            the_count +=10
        elif (i != 'A'):
            the_count += i
        else:
            ace_count +=1
    if (ace_count == 1 and the_count <= 10):
        the_count += 11
    elif(ace_count != 0):
        the_count += 1
    return the_count 

print ('Your cards are:' , player_hand) #printing the hands
print ("The dealer's cards are:" , '[' ,'X', ',', dealer_hand[0],  ']') #printing the hands


game = input('What would you like to do? H = HIT ME or S = Stand:  ')   #asking the user to hit or stand

if game == 'Hit': #drawing a card to the player's hand if he hits
    player_hand = random.choices(cards , k=1)
else:
    print(player_hand)

    print('You have:' , card_values(player_hand)) # telling the player's value if he stands

while card_values(dealer_hand) <= 16: #adding a card if the dealer's hand is less than 16
    dealer_hand = random.choices(cards , k=1)
```

### EDIT

If we are going to get into the style of scripts then we can start over entirely. This is a game so, automatically the first thing you need is a game loop. The next thing to do is simply 'play' the game with code. In blackjack the dealer and player get a hand. The first thing to happen in the game loop is for the dealer and player to get a hand. Both of those hands already have a value so we immediately get it and keep it updated the entire time. The next step is the player's choice to get hit or stand. We only need to know about 'hit'. 'hit' is the only choice that isn't the end of the game. Finally we simply compare the scores to concoct the proper message and print all of the game properties. The user is then asked if they want to run the loop again. Anything other than 'n' or 'no' is 'yes' ... regardless of our little message claiming something about a 'y'.

```
import random, os

# card references
facecards   = ['Ace', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
numcards    = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
# clears the console on windows
clear       = lambda: os.system('cls')


# calculate hand total
def sum(hand):
    c = 0
    for card in hand:
        if card != 'Ace':
            c += 10 if not card in numcards else int(card)
        else:
            c += 11 if c < 11 else 1
    return c


# create a shuffled deck    
def shuffled_deck(shuffles=3, cuts=2):
    deck     = [*facecards, *numcards] * 4
    shuffles = 3 if shuffles < 1 else shuffles
    cuts     = 2 if cuts < 1 else cuts

    for i in range(shuffles):
        random.shuffle(deck)

    for i in range(cuts):
        n = random.randint(1, len(deck))
        deck = [*deck[n::], *deck[0:n]]

    return deck


# the actual game    
def game_loop():
    playing = True              # we wont be 'playing' if the dealer busts
    deck    = shuffled_deck()   # get a fresh deck

    # you get a hand
    player_hand = [deck.pop(0), deck.pop(1)] # simulate alternating cards
    player      = sum(player_hand)

    #the dealer gets a hand
    dealer_hand = [deck.pop(0), deck.pop(0)] 
    dealer      = sum(dealer_hand)

    #the dealer continues to pick until the hand is worth at least 16
    while dealer < 16:
        dealer_hand.append(deck.pop(0))
        dealer  = sum(dealer_hand)
        playing = dealer <= 21

    # allow the player to keep getting hit as long as the player hasn't busted
    while playing:
        if player < 21:
            clear()
            print(f'\tDealer\ttotal: ??\tcards: X, {", ".join(dealer_hand[1::])}\n')
            print(f'\tPlayer\ttotal: {player}\tcards: {", ".join(player_hand)}\n')

            if input('\tTake a hit? (y)es or (n)o: ').lower() in ('y', 'yes'):
                player_hand.append(deck.pop(0))
                player = sum(player_hand)
                continue
            else:
                break
        else: 
            break

    # end of game        
    clear()    
    if player <= 21:
        if dealer > 21 or dealer <= player:
            print('\tCongratulations! You Are The Big Winner!\n')
        else:
            print('\tUnfortunately, You Lose.\n')
    else:
        print('\tYou Busted! Better Luck Next Time.\n')

    print(f'\tDealer\ttotal: {dealer}\tcards: {", ".join(dealer_hand)}\n')
    print(f'\tPlayer\ttotal: {player}\tcards: {", ".join(player_hand)}\n')

    if not input('\tWould you like to play again? (y)es or (n)o: ').lower() in ('n', 'no'):
        game_loop()
```

Comment: Let's replace `i` with `card`. I also find the ordering of conditions annoying to read. Why not `if card == "A": ace_count += 1` `elif card in ("J", "Q", "K"): the_count += 10` `else: the_count += card`.

Comment: I was fixing his error, not the entire code ;). Technically we could get rid of K,Q,J altogether. Something along the lines of this gist  `ACE if card == 'A' else card if card in cards else 10` and then simply change cards to `range(2,10)`

Comment: That would break the hand creation. `cards` does not need to ever appear in the function honestly.

Comment: Thanks @Guimoute and Micheal Guidry for the help and yes I am new on this platform and coding so my question style is still not right but I will hopefully improve that, thanks a lot for the feedback and explanation highly appreciate it

Comment: I strongly advise against using cryptic variable names like `a`, `c`, `h`, `player` and `dealer`...

Comment: I would agree if the game wasn't only 92 lines of code, if there were a lot more variables to juggle or if the logic was more complicated. In this case those names are perfect. There's no good reason to be extra specific in this case.